# How to check if a chr()'s output will be undefined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode, chr

I'm using chr() to run through a list of unicode characters, but whenever it comes across a character that is unassigned, it just continues running, and doesnt error out or anything. How do i check if the output of chr() will be undefined?

for example,

```
print(chr(55396))
```

is in range of unicode, it's just an unassigned character, how do i check what the output of chr() will give me an actual character that way this hangup doesn't occur?

Comment: That throws a `UnicodeEncodeError` for me. So, try catching that?

Comment: @grooveplex: You see that error only because you tried to `print` it (which tries to encode it in your system locale encoding); the character itself is created without error.

Comment: I was just following the example that OP gave, so if that's their actual code, they can try doing that.

Comment: I don't think it's unassigned. It's just a high surrogate without a corresponding low surrogate.

Comment: @grooveplex: The encoding error is a sort of backwards way of detecting this. The problem is they've made a high surrogate, which makes no sense without a paired low surrogate (and which really only makes sense if you're trying to decompose the string into UTF-16 form). It's a legal character, if paired properly, but in isolation it's gibberish.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: What do you consider to be "undefined"? Apparently you don't want to allow surrogate code points. What about [private-use characters and "noncharacters"](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html)?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the unicodedata module:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(chr(55396))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: no such name
>>> unicodedata.name(chr(120))
'LATIN SMALL LETTER X'
>>>
```

Comment: Flaw: `unicodedata.name(chr(0))` (along with tons of non-printing, but valid ASCII) has no name in the database. I was going to suggest this, but I don't think a solution that can't distinguish invalid characters from unnamed characters is viable in most cases.

Comment: I guess it depends on what the OP needs.

Comment: Perhaps. I was just checking though, and some of the unnamed characters will occur in real text. All ordinals below 32 are unnamed, including newlines, tabs, and carriage returns. I don't think you want to be told that `chr(10)` (aka `'\n'`) is an invalid character.